# Minimize button

Tags: updates, applications, user-interface

The OS is perfect, today I installed Elementary OS to test it, the system is very practical and beautiful, but it would be better with the minimize button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use elementary tweaks or pantheon tweaks (Odin 6.0) to bring minimize buttons back.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pantheon Tweaks to bring the minimise button back.

This is the link to the repo: https://github.com/pantheon-tweaks/pantheon-tweaks

Installation instructions can be found on the readme